# Bad omen to sew a garment while it is being worn

Tags: minhag

I've seen the "custom" by Jewish people, many times where someone will keep a piece of thread in their mouth while sewing a garment that is being worn.

Is there any source for this?

Comment: Wetting a thread makes it easier to feed through the eye of a needle

Comment: Have you only seen this among Jews?

Comment: @DoubleAA i edited the question for clarity.

Comment: @DoubleAA interestingly, the exact opposite is true for an elephant

Answer (score 5):

The [Kaf Hachaim YD (116:212)](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.116.212.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) brings the concern of forgetfulness.

המחליף  סנדל של שמאל בשל ימין קשה לשכחה וכן התופר בגדיו כשהוא מלובש. חופת אליהו שער ג' שה"נ או' שמ"א

Also, Rav Moshe Heinemann in **[Mah Nomar Chol HaMoed (5:6)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BW32R69V)** writes:

> "...It says in the Midrash Chupas Eliyahu Rabbah that a person should
> not sew clothes while wearing them because it is קָשֶׁה לְשִׁכְחָה.
> The Midrash is printed in the back of the Reishis Chochmah (3:61) in case you
> want to know where it is found. The velt says that if you chew a piece
> of thread while you are fixing it, then it is permitted.  However, it
> does not say that clearly in the Midrash. Some people say you should
> chew a piece of matzah while fixing it, but it does not that say
> either. This is a worldwide minhag so it is not just a bubbe-ma’aseh,
> though I don’t know the mekor, but it does say that you should not fix
> a garment while wearing it.
>
> Some say that not fixing the garment while wearing it comes from
> fixing the garment of a meis,  but there are a lot of things people
> say is forbidden because that is what they do for a meis that are not
> true. For instance, some say not cutting your fingernails k’seder is a
> problem  because that is how they cut the nails of a meis,  but I want
> to tell you some information: they do not cut the nails of a meis.
> Maybe many hundreds of years ago they did that,  but they have not cut
> the nails of a meis for many decades at least.  They do clean the
> nails, but they do not cut them.  Similarly, people say not to pour
> liquid out of a cup in the opposite direction, over the back of your
> hand, because that is what they do for a meis, but that is not true
> either. They pour liquid out like regular for a meis..."

Comment: Is the concern on the sewer or the wearer?